# Automating Browser with Cucumber with the use of Parameter

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

How to use parameter for example:

```
@When("^I enter \"([^\"]*)\" in the Keywords textbox$")
   public void I_enter_in_the_Keywords_textbox(String Job ) throws Throwable{
   driver.findElement(By.id(id)).sendKeys(Job);
 }
```

In the File I have:

```
When I enter "<Job>" in the keyword textbox
  |Job|
  |"QA"|
  |"Developer"|
```

I get Parser Error with gherkin. I tried using datatable, List and every possible way of getting different values but sendkeys doesn't work with Arrays, list or Tables.

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hm, I think you do not need to use quotation marks. I would write `QA` but not `"QA"`

Comment: Unfortunately, Whether the parameters are string or not it is the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You should using Scenario Outline like this:

Scenario Outline:Enter job name

```
 When I enter "<Job>" in the keyword textbox
```

Examples:

|Job|

|QA|

|Developer|

Comment: Indeed this is the issue. Faced the same problem and eventually found this link: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/367. After that, it worked great